# Windows message loops and WTL

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wtl

I'm trying to understand the way WTL works, and message loops are confusing me right now.

For example this code fragment: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/wtl4mfc2.aspx#premain2)

The window is first created and after that the message pump is started. How come it works? Isn't the CreateEx, UpdateWindow and so on supposed to send their own invisible messages like WM_CREATE/WM_PAINT/WM_NCPAINT? Where are they thrown if the message pump is not initialized? What happens if you create a window, start message loop, then close the window, but want to create a new one in it's place? PostQuit exits the loop and you have to create a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understanding the difference between posting messages (PostMessage) and sending messages (SendMessage) is important here.  Windows calls the window procedure directly for sent messages, they are not dispatched by the message loop.  Which is how WM_CREATE and WM_SHOWWINDOW can be processed before the message loop is started.  WM_QUIT, WM_PAINT, WM_KEYDOWN and WM_MOUSEMOVE are examples of messages that are posted.

Comment: So basically all posted messages are lost in this case? And you're better with creating the window from within the message loop?

Comment: No, they are stored in the message queue.  You cannot create a main window within a message loop, chicken and egg.  Petzold is required reading if you want to do this kind of programming.

Comment: Ok, I'll order the book today. But what makes the main window so special? You can start the loop, and post the "singleton" init message to the thread to create the window, that would do the trick, wouldn't it?

Comment: Not so sure why it is so important to you to do this a non-standard way.  PostThreadMessage is quite evil.  Read the book.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the internals and how to solve the problem correctly. "Intuitively" creating window from the message loop seems to be more correct. But the whole thing is still confusing. Not to mention all the crazy cases where MessageBoxW eats the message loop.

Comment: +1 for taking advice about buying Petzold!! Hans is absolutely right, this is where to start.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the message sending, `CreateWindow` sends the message directly, as if `SendMessage` were used. If you've done much Windows programming, you'll probably have sent messages to controls directly in this way, and had things happen immediately without needing the message pump to run; Windows will do this itself, too.

As for the `PostQuitMessage` issue, the usual tactic is to have some other check in the message loop to see if the application should exit. For example, rather than posting a quit message on window close and waiting for `WM_QUIT` in the message loop, you could maintain a counter of open windows then just quit if there are 0 open windows.

There is nothing magic about `WM_QUIT`, except for the convenient way you can post it with `PostQuitMessage` and easily check for it with the `GetMessage` (etc.) functions. You are free not to use it and decide to exit your program for some other reason.